# angular universal : social sharing page items

Tags: angular, typescript, meta-tags, angular-universal

I am developing an Angular poll app which displays an items list on my homepage. I added a social sharing button on each item to share it on Facebook or Twitter.

An item example :

[image]

My problem is each item got an image and I want this image appears on the thumbnail when I share it.

I tried something :

- Transform my Angular app to Angular universal app
- Add the possibility to add the id of an item in my url params (https://dev.mysite/home/5fd9ca6914c78f9f5a8cc86d)
- Set the url with the item id params on each share button
- In my server.ts, get the item id in url params, call my backend to get the item datas and image url and update the home page meta tags

index.html

```
      <meta name="description" content="$DESCRIPTION"/> 
      <meta name="metaDescription" content="$OG_META_DESCRIPTION"/> 
      <meta property="og:title" content="$OG_TITLE" />
      <meta property="og:description" content="$OG_DESCRIPTION" />
      <meta property="og:image" content="$OG_IMAGE" />
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
      <meta name="twitter:site" content="$TWITTER_SITE">
      <meta name="twitter:creator" content="$TWITTER_CREATOR">
      <meta name="twitter:title" content="$TWITTER_TITLE">
      <meta name="twitter:description" content="$TWITTER_DESCRIPTION">
      <meta name="twitter:image" content="$TWITTER_IMAGE">
```

servert.ts

```
<meta name="description" content="$DESCRIPTION"/> 
<meta name="metaDescription" content="$OG_META_DESCRIPTION"/> 
<meta property="og:title" content="$OG_TITLE" />
<meta property="og:description" content="$OG_DESCRIPTION" />
<meta property="og:image" content="$OG_IMAGE" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="$TWITTER_SITE">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="$TWITTER_CREATOR">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="$TWITTER_TITLE">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="$TWITTER_DESCRIPTION">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="$TWITTER_IMAGE">
```

It seems to work for Facebook sharing, but on Twitter the update of twitter tags is done when I check the source code of the page but on the sharing popup the image do not appears.

Twitter share code :

```
  shareOnTwitter() {
    // Opens a pop-up with twitter sharing dialog
    var shareURL = 'http://twitter.com/share?'; //url base
    //params
    const text = this.item.title;
    const user ='username';

    var params = {
      url: `${environment.base_url}/home/${this.item.id}`,
      text: text,
      via: user,
      hashtags: hashtagsString,
    };
    for (var prop in params)
      shareURL += '&' + prop + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[prop]);
    window.open(
      shareURL,
      '',
      'left=0,top=0,width=550,height=450,personalbar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0'
    );
  }
```

I'm blocked with this problems for days !! I'm a little bit lost and I don't find the solution !! Can someone help me with this.

bonus question : I also don't have any solution to share it on WhatsApp with the item thumbnail, when I copy/paste the link on whatsapp I got the default metatags i setted, where does WhatsApp get the meta infos ??

Thank you in advance for help !

Bye

Alex

Comment: I am facing the same issue. But my facebook sharing also does not work can you share the code. Thanks in advance.